# How do I get over 100+ stats in game dev story?

Tags: game-dev-story

The max that I was able to get the stats at is 65+.  How do I get the stats even higher?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get such stats (even 300+ in all) if you have a great dev team/staff. It will take some time but it is worth it. You need to get the great staff and train them and level them up. You can hire 3 special characters as the game progresses and you win game of the year awards and sell millions of copies. Just be patient.

Answer (score -2):

You need high stats people and the salesman comes at month 5 week 2 you can buy a boost there. I recommend fun boost but for the boost to work well use it one the best person with programming.If u buy others again with best fun and best in graphics and sound. I hope this will help.